# Mockito can't mock EntityManager

Tags: jpa, junit, mockito

I'm starting with Mockito, and after reading several examples doing this, I can't mock the javax.persistence.EntityManager. It gives me:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Mockito cannot mock this class: interface javax.persistence.EntityManager.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
```

Yes, indeed EntityManager is an interface, but why there's too many examples doing things like this...

```
this.em = Mockito.mock(EntityManager.class);
```

or this...

```
@Mock
EntityManager em;
```

... and it works?

I've tried changes a lot of thinks, like the annotations

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

or

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

or

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

Tried either removing the @Mock and doing with:

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

But none of that works.
I'm awareabout whether or not it's really necessary to mock the entitymanager, but I really want to know what's wrong.

Comment: There should also be a stacktrace for this error... Can you please share that? Also, how are trying to run the test? CLI or IDE (which one)? Or both?

Comment: On top of stacktrace - Are you using mockito-core or mockkito-inline? What version?